# Google Analytics - unique page views higher than page views

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews, google-analytics-filters

Creating a customer dashboard to see metrics for when users who have a GUID (filter GUID regular expression ^[a-zA-Z0-9_=-]+$).

For one week of data the metrics are showing:

- Page views - 2,355,275 (% of Total: 60.27% (3,908,039))
- Unique page views - 2,936,422 (% of Total: 93.88% (3,127,742))

**How can the unique page views be higher than the page views?**

The fact that the total for page views is higher than the total for unique page views makes me think it's something to do with the filter, but the same filter is applied to each widget so this doesn't make sense.

EDIT: The dashboard is also showing Users as higher than Sessions (654,264 vs 565,969)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related question may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ where experts in Google Analytics filtering can be found.

Comment: Do you get the same result when looking at a single day of data?  My initial thought is that this is due to data sampling as you mention the % of totals.